# Как мы видим модальное окно при нажатии на back button click?

Tags: ajax

Ajax:
Как мы видим модальное окно при нажатии на back button click?

Comment: @diraria переведено.

Comment: @NickVolynkin никто не отвечает правда)

Comment: @diraria я не очень понимаю вопрос, если честно. В Ajax есть какая-то каноническая и всем знакомая кнопка back? А модальное окно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну я тоже не очень понимаю, но если посмотреть на [другой вопрос автора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/720950/227016), то, видимо, под кнопкой back имеется в виду навигация назад по истории, а ajax тут вообще ни при чём)

Comment: Mika, пока что непонятно, чем этот вопрос отличается от вопроса [Модальное окно!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/720950/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be).